# flutter app architecture and state management with provider, correct usage?

Tags: flutter, architecture, flutter-provider

I'm working on understanding the flow of data through a flutter application and state management methods. I made this flow chart to try and create a visual of what I hope to do to help guide me. All the firebase reads and writes are going through UserModel (small application, only data that is variable is UserModel which is like a profile + stats etc.), this way I can save locally or push to firebase when the user has an online connection.

[image: data flow through widgets]

widgets in green are displayed, in total this app is only two pages, main page and onboarding. Mainpage is comprised of a navigation bar with two screen widgets and a modal on one of those screens.

**My question is**, is the structure that I have above an efficient and logical use of these tools? Suggestions on improving it if necessary?

Also, the pathing arrow between firebase and user model should be two way

Comment: Shouldn't main have arrow to UserModel which has arrow to FirebaseUserModel? And yes it seems logical.